# No reconoce el comando npm start AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

estoy intentando arrancar un proyecto con AngularJS, ya había hecho proyectos con Angular2-4-6-7, pero es la primera vez con AngularJs.

El caso que al importar el proyecto, he visto que no tenía la carpeta node modules, así que he hecho el npm install.

```
    PS D:proyecto> npm install
    npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ because the host is inaccessible -- are you offline?
    npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
    npm WARN deprecated gulp-clean-css@2.4.0: breaking changes from clean-css 4.x. Please install gulp-clean-css 3.x
    npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
    npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
    npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
    npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
    npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
    npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js

> node-sass@3.13.1 install D:\proyecto\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node":

tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall D:\proyecto\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\proyecto\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'D:\\proyecto\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@8.11.3 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\proyecto\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\proyecto\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\proyecto\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\proyecto\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\proyecto\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\proyecto\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\proyecto\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\proyecto\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\proyecto\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\proyecto\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\proyecto\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\proyecto\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (D:\\proyecto\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (D:\\proyecto\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (D:\\proyecto\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at D:\\proyecto\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at D:\\proyecto\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at D:\\proyecto\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Program Files\Python36\python.EXE
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\Python36\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:557:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\proyecto\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd D:\proyecto\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-11T13_30_53_894Z-debug.log
PS D:\proyecto> npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-11T13_33_45_613Z-debug.log
```

Aún así la carpeta del node modules se crea.

El archivo del log tiene:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.11.3
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:151:19)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:61:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:115:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:402:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:357:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:400:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:160:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:332:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:420:13)
5 verbose cwd D:\proyecto
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
8 verbose node v8.11.3
9 verbose npm  v5.6.0
10 error missing script: start
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Se queja de algo del python, pero entonces no hubieran funcionado los proyecto de angular2... Bueno, tampoco entiendo mucho, espero que puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Edito: cuando empecé a usar angular2, mi jefe me dijo que me instalara el yarnk para ejecutar los proyectos de angular2 con yarn start, lo he probado y tampoco funciona.

Comment: Lo que veo por encima del **error** es que en el `package.json` no existe el `script` asignado a `start`

Comment: ¿ **Desde tu navegador** puedes acceder a `https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/` ?

Comment: intenta `npm install` y luego `npm start` de igual forma lo que dice @Trauma es correcto y al no poder instalar node-sass te da el error

Comment: Si no me equivoco, `gyp` trabaja con Python 2, por lo visto tienes la versión 3. ¿Puedes instalar Python 2 y probar?

Comment: @Trauma, no me da error 404

Comment: @JackNavaRow , eso es lo que hago, el install y después el start y nada.

Comment: @DanielMauricioSánchezÁvila he puesto la línea   "start": "ng serve", y tampoco

Comment: y probando directamente el comando `ng serve`? aun no funciona?

Comment: El término 'ng' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable.

Comment: @MauricioContreras ya lo instalé, sigue igual, al hacer el npm install parece ser que no encuentra algo en la carpeta \node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)

Comment: agrega el package.json la linea del node-sass

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente bajé la versión del NODE.JS porque anteriormente yo usaba angular2 y el proyecto al ser de angularJS había que bajarle la versión.

Además ejecuté los comandos:

```
npm install -g windows-build-tools
npm install -g gulp
npm install
gulp
```

Espero que le sirva a alguien.